# How to plugin already written C/C++ layer in chainer

Tags: chainer

I have already written C++ layer which is using CPU, I want to plugin chainer framework, How to do that ? Can chainer mix of CPU and GPU layers together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cython, pybind11, or whatever tool to call C++ code from Python to embed your C++ layer into Chainer. You have to write a little bit of glue code to do that (e.g. converting NumPy array buffer from/to the data format used in the layer written in C++ and converting the interface of you layer into Chainer style Function; the latter should be easily done by writing a small Python class).

In order to mix CPU and GPU in your forward/backward computations, you can use `F.copy()`; it supports backprop (see https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.functions.copy.html?highlight=copy).

Comment: You said: converting the interface of you layer into Chainer style Function? How to write C++ layer interface like chainer style function?? do not understand about this sentence.

Comment: oh , I understand, You mean modify C++ code to function, and chainer link call the C++ function? (not C++ layer?)

Comment: Yes. It would be very complicated to make C++ code manage parameters of Chainer. It's much simpler to write a Function that internally calls the C++ code (some modifications to the C++ code would be needed to align the interface) and to write Link that calls the Function.